# Searching for a specific Feynman quote

Tags: soft-question

Pardon that this is strictly speaking not a question about physics but about a quote about physics, but I'm not sure where else to turn to.

A while back I read a quote by Feynman in which he says something to the effect that the more different ways one can solve a physics problem the more deeply one understands it.

Unfortunately, I don't remember where I read this. I spent significant amount of time googling as well as looking through my Feynman lectures but could not locate it.

Does anyone know where to find the quote?

Thanks

Comment: Try the Nobel Lecture (link below) .  Search for "fundamental laws of physics".

http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1965/feynman-lecture.html

Comment: Hi arminrph, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! As you suspected, I don't think this is on topic for us; exact quotes are generally of no importance in physics.